# Timezone selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function calcTime(offset) 
{
    d = new Date();
    utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));
    return "The local time is " + nd.toLocaleString();  }      
alert(calcTime('-8'));
alert(calcTime('-7'));
alert(calcTime('-6'));
alert(calcTime('-5'));
</script>
```

'In this I have 4 alerts to show timezone's time and date.and at every load of page it shows all 4 alerts... but i want to show the value of alerts in textbox with dropdown selection.
    i have 4 drop down values Pacific, Mountain, Central And Eastern timezone.
    I want to show result value in textbox on dropdown selection. Please help to solve this problem. '

Comment: Here's the `Pseudocode` .. you need to create a listener for your dropdown menu.. after that condition the selected value on what timezone it belongs.. get the value and display in textbox. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you ask for:

`<select name="timezone" onChange="calcTime(this.value)">`

Update

*Javascript:*

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function calcTime(offset) 
{
    d = new Date();
    utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));
    document.getElementById('result').value=nd.toLocaleString();
}      
</script>
```

*HTML:*

`<input type="text" name="result" id="result" value="">`

Comment: What is the UI result of this code ?